# Shorthand code working, but using brackets brakes the function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a function were I loop through some gameObjects and change an int if it's not 0. The strange thing is, some of the parts stop working when I add brackets for better readability. I'm currently using the code below, but would like that extra readability and efficiency when calling the function.

```
WetStepCycle(leftFoot, lfHit);
if (wetStepsRemainingLeft != 0) wetStepsRemainingLeft--;

private void WetStepCycle(Transform footTransform, RaycastHit footHit)
    {
        if (currentActive == wetStepDecals.Length - 1) currentActive = 0;
        else
        currentActive++;
        wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.position = new Vector3(footTransform.position.x, footHit.point.y, footTransform.position.z);
        wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.eulerAngles = footTransform.transform.eulerAngles;
    }
```

This is working like a charm, but not very compact, I would like the substracting the int within the function.

```
private void WetStepCycleTest(Transform footTransform, RaycastHit footHit, int sCounter)
    {
        if (currentActive == wetStepDecals.Length - 1)
        {
            currentActive = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentActive++;
            wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.position = new Vector3(footTransform.position.x, footHit.point.y, footTransform.position.z);
            wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.eulerAngles = footTransform.transform.eulerAngles;
            if (sCounter != 0)
            {
                sCounter--;
                Debug.Log("Minus");
            }
        }
    }
```

This for some reason isn't working and I think it has something to do with formatting. This way the sCounter isn't substracted and for some reason the first item of the gameObject array isn't used. I think it has to do with doing currentActive++ and sCounter--;, but changing them to += 1 and -= 1 doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: If you dont use brackets, only the first statement after the if or else is considered part of the condition.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong in the bottom part if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net, when you write the if / else / foreach statements, the curly braces are optional. Thats **only** when you have one statement after the if / else..

```
// Example without curly braces
if (true)
  Console.Write("true")

else 
  Console.Write("false)

Console.Write("Will Execute After the if else");
```

and if you have multiple statements / block that needs to be inserted within either if or else, you would use it like this,

```
if (true)
  Console.WriteLine("true")
else
{
  Conosle.Write("This ");
  Console.Write("Is ");
  Console.Write("False");
}
```

If you try to write multiple statements within one line, that will result in errors.

```
    if (true)
        Console.Write("This"); Console.Write("Is"); Console.Write("True"); 
        // Error Here: 'Else Cannot start a statement'. Syntax error ( expected, invalid expression ....
    else
        Console.Write("Whaaa");
```

**Your Code**

If your first block works and not the second, its because you are running more statements in your else block than you need to.

```
    private void WetStepCycleTest(Transform footTransform, RaycastHit footHit, int sCounter)
    {
        if (currentActive == wetStepDecals.Length - 1)
        {
            currentActive = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            currentActive++;
        }

        wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.position = new Vector3(footTransform.position.x, footHit.point.y, footTransform.position.z);
        wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.eulerAngles = footTransform.transform.eulerAngles;
        if (sCounter != 0)
        {
            sCounter--;
            Debug.Log("Minus");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This clears it up alot, thank you for that. The strange thing is however sCounter still isn't substracted, but the Minus log is working. Any idea why sCounter is not being substracted?

Comment: `scounter` is subtracted within that statement but it is not saved anywhere. It goes away right after the execution of the method you have. Each time you call the method, sCounter will always be the same unless you are updating it before calling this method

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? When I do it out of the function it is working (if (wetStepsRemainingLeft != 0) wetStepsRemainingLeft--;), but when trying it within the function with sCounter being wetSteosRemainingLeft or wetStepsRemainingRight it isn't working

Comment: `scounter` is passed into this function. If `scounter` is decremented within this function, it does not change it in the main class that called this method, 'WetStepCycleTest'. After this method completes, the value of `scounter` reverts to what it was in the main class that called this said method. **scounter exists only within this method**.

Comment: Ah ok, so if I understand it correctly within the function it's happening but it didn't actually change the value of wetStepsRemainingLeft. How would I be able to set this value?

Comment: Correct! You will have to return this value so that calling method would be updated or update scounter outside of this method altogether

Comment: What does returning this look like in code if I may ask? I am using return for something like a public bool, but I have no idea how to return a value within a method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206205/discussion-between-jawad-and-quincy-norbert).

Answer (score 2):

your else in the top only apply to currentActive++ and in the bottom to all the code below

this would be the corresponding transform

```
private void WetStepCycleTest(Transform footTransform, RaycastHit footHit, int sCounter)
{
    if (currentActive == wetStepDecals.Length - 1)
    {
        currentActive = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        currentActive++;                
    }

    wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.position = new Vector3(footTransform.position.x, footHit.point.y, footTransform.position.z);
    wetStepDecals[currentActive].transform.eulerAngles = footTransform.transform.eulerAngles;
}
```

I would personaly prefere

```
currentActive = (currentActive + 1 ) % wetStepDecals.Length;
```